# Docker - docker compose two branches - Updated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to using Docker.

I'm using Dockerhub to link up with my GitHub repo. I have two branches on my GitHub repo: master and test. I want to know how to use `docker-compose` to specifically build either the master project (live) or the test project (development). Do I specify the tag name? when using:

`docker-compose up -d`

Because right now it only builds master project.

[image]

**Updated docker-compose.yml**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    image: melkawakibi/blogandportfolio:latest
  links:
     - db

  web:
    image: melkawakibi/blogandportfolio:test
  links:
     - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ""
      MYSQL_USER: ""
```

dockerfile

```
FROM hitalos/laravel

RUN git config --system http.sslverify false

RUN git clone @github.com/melkawakibi/blogandportfolio.git /var/www

RUN cp .env.production .env

# Run Compser Install
RUN composer install -d /var/www
RUN php /var/www/artisan key:generate

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD php /var/www/artisan serve --port=80 --host=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `image: melkawakibi/blogandportfolio:master` for `master` branch, and `image: melkawakibi/blogandportfolio:test` for `test` branch. The absence of a tag implies `latest`, that you don't have.

Comment: So what is the command I need to run, right now I'm running docker-compose up -d and it only builds the master branch? Should I name the master branch latest?

Comment: The command is fine, just change your `docker-compose.yml` accordingly as I showed. It shouldn't even build the master branch based on the screenshot you've above, because you don't have any images with `latest` tag. Or maybe you do locally, you didn't say.

Comment: I updated the docker-compose.yml file. I still have troubles building it. It only builds the test version.